# How do I run execute commands from a git repo from Python? Shell + Docker

Tags: bash, git, docker, shell

My goal is to run a docker container that will simulate a physical device that sends requests to an external API.

The simulator lives in a GitHub repo and after cloning it is run by bash scripts that:

1. Set up a virtualenv.
2. Run maven build.
3. Execute other commands via Python that runs a docker container.
4. It can also remove docker container.

How can I simplify these dependencies and make sure everything is packed in a working container (application that otherwise would be run through shell scripts)?

Comment: What have you already tried?  What problems are you encountering?

Comment: @DavidMaze So far I tried running shell commands from Python. But would it be a good idea? Look, Python that runs shell commands that run bash scripts that call another Python repo scripts that run shell commands and spin up a docker container. It seems to me like a way to overwhelm the whole thing. It's like one project runs another project and for another project to execute it should be copied to the first project.

Comment: Apparently Maven builds a docker image as well, so I might take it and reuse it, omitting many redundant steps.